# Ajax call showing error when call ActionResult in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using Angularjs with asp.net MVC. I want to save data using ajax hit but it is showing Error message And in browser it is showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". I want to call 
Action result once for test with a static id but it is not working. My View page is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SaveOwn";
}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    (function (angular) {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('SaveOwnData', [])
          .controller('SaveOwnDataController', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.saveData = {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                designation: '',
                mobile: ''
            }
            $scope.save = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: { "id": "1" },
                    url: "/Home/SaveData",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            };
        }]);
    })(window.angular);

</script>

<div ng-app="SaveOwnData" ng-controller="SaveOwnDataController as saveData" ng-init="id=0; name=0;designation=0; mobile=0 ">
    <input type="text" ng-model="saveData.id" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="saveData.name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="saveData.designation" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="saveData.mobile" />
    <input type="button" data-ng-click="save()" value="Save" />
    {{saveData.total()}}
    {{saveData.mobile}}
</div>
```

ActionResult code is:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

i want to call SaveData method once as demo with ajax then i will use all parameters. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it help to remove quotes from the id parameter in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for help me but there was another problem.
 The problem is resolved after using JSON.stringify in my code i have successfully called to action as :

```
$scope.save = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "id": "1" }),
                url: "/Home/SaveData",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Json ActionResult in this case, i assume there is no View called "SavedData" (e.g. a Savedata.cshtml).   You should check chrome network tab and view what the error was but most likely this is why.  it would be returned there.

Try it like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string id)
{
    return Json(new{status: "success"}); //return json status...
}
```

Can read the result like:

```
  $scope.save = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: { "id": "1" },
                    url: "/Home/SaveData",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.status);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: i am facing same problem after all changes , There is same errors in chrome Network tab as: " POST http://localhost:1362/Home/SaveData 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4$scope.save @ (index):17(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12345f @ angular.js:21438l.$eval @ angular.js:14401l.$apply @ angular.js:14500(anonymous function) @ angular.js:21443c @ angular.js:3014"

Comment: It is also showing "GET http://localhost:1362/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)" before 500 error

Comment: hello, ok... so the network tab, if you click on it (under name), there should be a split window on the right show up, with  "headers", "preview", "response" tabs.   if you click preview, you should get the actual .net error... this way we can see exactly what it's complaining about.   There could be routing issues or some other factors, if you put a breakpoint in the SaveData does it ever land there?

Comment: Also, don't worry about the 404 not found, that's for the browser icon (favicon) that you don't have.

Comment: Thanks sir i have resolved the problem.... And post the full code in answers..Thank you to help me...

Answer (score 0):

Modify AJAX call parameter to use a URL starting with `~` like so: `~/Home/SaveData`.

Also, verify you have placed the [HttpPost] attribute as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have edited as you give but having same problem error in message and in browser console message is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Some time it showing "POST http://localhost:58051/Home/SaveData 500 (Internal Server Error)" in browser console...